# How to disable prettier settings creating new line of > of html tag?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

I walk through the Prettier extension of Vscode and I can't find how to disable this scenario. See the > of html tag.

Here's a sample code that needed some fix, every time i run the Prettier. The output is this:

```
<tag-html
 [val1]="valueStr"
 [val2]="valueStr"
>
</tag-html>
```

I want Prettier to output:

```
<tag-html
 [val1]="valueStr"
 [val2]="valueStr">
</tag-html>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

For `JSX` (and other file types, like `HTML`) this can be done setting

> "bracketSameLine": true

in your .prettierrc

see https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-line

(or `jsxBracketSameLine` for versions < 4.2.0)

Comment: This is deprecated as of `4.2.0`. Replaced with `bracketSameLine`

Comment: I also needed to add htmlWhitespaceSensitivity: ignore in order for it to work.

Comment: @styks Your answer helped my project work again. I think older versions of React Native new project templates still use the old `jsxBracketSameLine` key and it therefore stopped working after I updated my Prettier. IMO they should have deprecated it but not removed it.

Comment: worked for me, thanks a lot. mark it to correct answer.

Answer (score 20):

This can be done with help of VS Code itself. Place the following entry in your workspace settings in your vs code.

```
"html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned"
```

You don't need any external plugins or extension to do this.

Or you can use the GUI settings page as well

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE 01**

Based on github issue in prettier repo
https://github.com/prettier/prettier-vscode/issues/646

you can still merge the settings I have mentioned above.

Comment: hi, thank you for the answer, I worked when not using prettier, but I need the extension as it is being used already on the project.

Comment: This is a poor answer as it doesn't address the question. I came here from Google looking for the prettier solution as I don't use VS Code.

Comment: @ChrisTurner It might not answer your question. But answered the real question, and question-asker accepted the answer at that time (2018). If you really have any specific questions, please raise - happy to answer if possible.

Comment: i take "html.format.wrapAttributes": "force-aligned" - nothing has changed, sign ">" transfer, what need check more?

Comment: "you can still merge the settings" - you linked to a very, very long thread that I don't have time to read. How can you merge settings? I just tried setting that setting, and it changes nothing. Merge how?

Comment: The conclusion of that thread is to avoid using Prettier for HTML:
"[We] ignored all file types other than `*.html` using the `beautify.ignore` workspace setting and added `*.html` to `.prettierignore`. So Beautify only formats HTML and Prettier formats everything else."

Comment: This isn't helpful. Remember, there are teams who use prettier because it is IDE agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me for Prettier settings:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Putting the prettier configuration file in the project root directory was **the only working solution** for me such as `.prettierrc.json` ([Read More](https://prettier.io/docs/en/configuration.html))

After the creation of the configuration file, put the below setting into it:

```
{
  "bracketSameLine": true,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "semi": true,
  "singleQuote": true,
  "htmlWhitespaceSensitivity": "ignore"
}
```

Save the settings and it will work as expected.