# Stop Prettier formatter from putting each HTML tag on its own line in React JSX files?

Tags: html, reactjs, visual-studio-code, prettier

When I format an HTML file using prettier, it looks like this:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" title="Home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="About">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Sign Up">Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" title="Careers">Careers</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

But when I put the same tags in a JSX file, it reformats it like this:

```
import React from "react";

const Demo = () => {
  return (
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a title="Home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a title="About">About</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a title="Sign Up">Sign Up</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a title="Contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a title="Careers">Careers</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Demo;
```

How can I stop this behavior? It happens even with a high value for `prettier.printWidth`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After more reading I've concluded this isn't possible. HTML is whitespace sensitive so it is retained, but since JSX isn't it gets autoformatted always and Prettier has no option to keep tags on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with `jsx` when using Prettier. I had unwanted curly brackets {" "} (AKA jsx spaces) and separate lines for each tag, when the following input:

```
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span className='quote'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></p>;
```

gave the following output:

```
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet{" "}
  <span className="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span>
</p>;
```

[prettier playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEACAPABwHwBkIBOcAtqgJaYDOArqQCYQA2hqlZMqAhsXB+pZk5RUYRp0qUActzgBeAOQBHahHjy8hEuSq1UDZgVbsuPGOgD0Aodgs4A3CAA0ICJhhlolZKE4ECEAHcABV8ELxROADcIMjonEAAjAk4wAGteAGUZXDIoOGQAM05GSjhnJJT0mAzBMFyAc2QYAmoykFLiMiaWtrgAD0w4AjIeWGKAFSGoXzI4cKKStrYoesY4AEUVeELi0ucAK0o+jIa1zdV8pAW9kGULoP8qZBBxAFo8uDpP+ObOMkYGgBhCDEYicZ5QaD5ZzLVZwACCMGaZAS1HgQSGOTyO0WzgAFjBiIwAOp49hzWpwDJhdhkSLsACezzAEnikVaAEkoF9YBkwMM3PDuRkYAy1jibph-KViclMM8pXMhpFoSBcqUCDAHpx6mCJW1BAQNc8EpwEnBGPEpbkYMTYjA8cgABwABmcRGUZCI2t14KuuzaMDNdroDuQACZnNRSuMzfMA84SOa6F86LghPVqDq4AAxQhgpENZ6cNEQeLiGD65wMMBVkCHPoAIWSaUy2Vyl2ubQgaMwaPD+oAvoOgA)

The only option to get rid of this behaviour seems to be adding `//prettier-ignore` everywhere, which is far from ideal solution. With `//prettier-ignore`, this input:

```
const IndexPage = () =>
  // prettier-ignore
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span className="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></p>;
```

gives this output:

```
const IndexPage = () =>
  // prettier-ignore
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <span className="quote">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</span></p>;
```

so  `<span>` won't end up on its own line.

Answer (score -1):

Prettier has the option `printWidth`. You can change it to something large value in `settings.json`. It's a bit of a stretch, but it works.

```
"prettier.printWidth": 140
```

Answer (score -2):

You should be able to curve this by using

```
"bracketSameLine": true
```

In the prettier config
[JSX Brackets](https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#bracket-line)

This also could be of some help [How to disable prettier settings creating new line of > of html tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53927236/how-to-disable-prettier-settings-creating-new-line-of-of-html-tag)

Comment: Just tried that but it doesn't fix it. It says `Put the > ... at the end of the last line instead of being alone on the next line` which doesn't apply here. All my tags have `<` and `>` on the same line, but I want multiple tags kept on the same line